# Getting an object's links in Rackspace cloud files API

Tags: rackspace-cloud, rackspace, cloudfiles, jclouds

I am using the Java jclouds API for access to my Rackspace cloud files account.

I can create and list containers, and upload objects, but I can't figure out how to get the public links for an uploaded object. (I can see these public links from within the Rackspace control panel, by right-clicking on the object - there are 4 types: HTTP, HTTPS, Streaming, iOS Streaming).

The closest I can get is by using object.getInfo() to get the object's metadata. This includes a URI, but this doesn't resemble the public links I find from within the control panel.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out...

First, I should get the public URI of the object's container, not from the object.

Then I use a **CloudFilesClient** object. On the container I need to use `getCDNMetadata("containername").getCDNUri()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is more information and some sample code to get the specific file CDN address.
For more details you can checkout the Java guide:
https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/quickstart/?lang=java

First get the cloud files api:

```
    CloudFilesApi cloudFilesApi = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("rackspace-cloudfiles-us")
        .credentials("{username}", "{apiKey}")
        .buildApi(CloudFilesApi.class);
```

From there you can query the container:

```
    CDNApi cdnApi = cloudFilesApi.getCDNApi("{region}");
    CDNContainer cdnContainer = cdnApi.get("{containerName}");
```

Now with that CDNContainer you can get the specific web address that you need:

```
    URI httpURI = cdnContainer.getUri();
    URI httpsURI = cdnContainer.getSslUri();
```

This will get you the base URI for the container. Now to get the final address for your specific file you will need to append */{"your_file_name.extension"}* to the end of the address. For example if my base URI was converted to a URL then to a String it may look like:

```
    http://123456asdf-qwert987653.rackcdn.com/
```

From here I can get a file with the name **example.mp4** with the following address:

```
    http://123456asdf-qwert987653.rackcdn.com/example.mp4
```

This all assumes that you have already enabled CDN on the container.